# array doesn't fix "local variable 'x' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, scope, variable-assignment

Why does this python code still raise the "local variable  referenced before assignment" error?

```
class GameObject():
x=[0]
y=[0]
file = "images/initImage.jpg"
image = pygame.image.load('images/initImage.jpg')
def __init__(self,file):
    self.file=file
    image = pygame.image.load(file).convert()
    gameobjects.append(self)

def update(a):
    x[0]+=10
```

I was under the impressing using a single-element array fixed this issue. I also tried using the global and nonlocal statements, they didn't work either. I apologize if this question is a duplicate, but implementing fixes i saw in other questions didn't seem to work.

Comment: On which line? read the error properly / paste the error here in your code.

Comment: Why are `x` and `y` class variables? Should they be instance variables? If they *are* supposed to be class variables, take note that name resolution in methods **does not** check the class or instance.

Comment: sorry the error is on the line:
x[0]+=10
I am afraid I am not at the level to fully understand you comment  user2357112, could you phrase in slightly simpler terms?

Comment: Hint, try with using an instance variable *after* making `update` a method: `def update(self): self.x[0] += 10` (also, make sure code is formatted correctly in questions, as interpretation of the "intent" could be wrong)

Comment: user2864740, your solution worked, thank you. for future reference where is the formatting problem?

Comment: The indentation is screwed up. Code formatting on this site is confusing; copy-paste your code into the question, select it, *then* hit the code-formatting button. Don't hit the button and then paste, or paste and then manually indent the first line.

Comment: @user2357112 why you revert back the indent ? If you are trying to teach OP a lesson on code formatting on SO; then it's OK, never mind.

Comment: @TanmayaMeher: It's not clear whether `update` is supposed to be a method or a module-level function. In ambiguous cases like this, I think it's better to leave the original indentation up until (unless) the questioner corrects it.

Comment: that was a formatting error I didn't notice, it's done properly in my  actual code, I'll take note of that in future posts, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use python lists - python really does not have arrays :

The following code snippet uses instance attributes - as suggested by @user2864740

I assume that gameobjects is a global variable ? if so the code will work, but it is not a great design - ideally a class should be self contained - a better design would be for your caller to create a GameObject and then add that to the gameobjects list as a 2nd step.

```
class GameObject():
    def __init__(self,file):
        self.x, self.y = 0 
        self.file= "images/initImage.jpg"
        self.image = pygame.image.load(file).convert()
        gameobjects.append(self)

    def update(self, a):
        self.x+=10
```

You will note that I have made "update" a real instance method - which I think it should be, although it wasn't clear what your "a" argument is used for - so I kept it.

NB : In future if you get the "“local variable 'x' referenced before assignment” error, don't automatically try to solve it by making converting your variable into a list. Although in some cases that might be the right solution, what you will need to do is look at where you use your variable : what the error message is actually saying is that you used the variable on the right-hand side of an expression/statement before you use it on the left hand side - i.e you are trying to use the value of your variable, before you give your variable a value. The solution is almost always going to be either :

- A missing initialisation of your variable
- A scope issue - where you have initialised your variable, but not in the same scope of where you try to use it : That was your original problem (x was initialised as a class attribute, but you were trying to use it as if it was a global).

There maybe some other causes (I can't think of anything right now), but these two are the most common.

Comment: Oh, it makes much more sense now, thank you. you are correct in assuming it isn't global.

Comment: Can you either upvote or accept (or both) this answer please, if you understand it, and it answers your question - thanks.